# How to wait for a request from a different URL in Cypress test?

Tags: cypress, cypress-intercept

In my Cypress test, I am trying to wait for a GET request & validate it's response. However, the test is timing out as the request never occurs.

Here is the request I am trying to wait for:

[image]

Here are some details around the test:

- The URL of the app I am visiting in the test is `https://ts-e2e-challenge.netlify.app/list`.
- In my test, an action is performed that sends a GET request to the URL `https://bookshelf.jk/api/list-items`, as you can see in the screenshot.

And here is my test code:

```
cy.intercept('GET', '/list-items').as('getListItems')
cy.wait('@getListItems').then((interception) => {
});
```

Full error message:

> Timed out retrying after 5000ms: cy.wait() timed out waiting 5000ms
> for the 1st request to the route: getListItems. No request ever occurred

I assume the URL that I am trying to intercept is incorrect, but I have tried to update it to the full path `https://bookshelf.jk/api/list-items`, but the request is still not being made.

Can someone please point out what the request URL should be based on the above screenshot?

Answer (score 1):

There's a service worker intercepting the network requests before Cypress can intercept them.

If you put `https://bookshelf.jk/api/list-items` into a normal browser, it can't be reached. That's because the service worker is acting like the (non-existing) API server.

For the record, the full URL `https://bookshelf.jk/api/list-items` should work. Also `/api/list-items` would work if your `baseUrl` was common to the web page and the api (as you surmised).

As far as I can see, there's no simple adjustment to fix it. You may be able to hack the loading of the service worker but if you're just trying out `cy.intercept()` it's not worth the effort.

I'd look for another site to test against, [https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com](https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/) is a good one.

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue here is your request is not intercepted properly, You can try this:

```js
cy.intercept('GET', '**/api/list-items').as('getListItems')
cy.wait('@getListItems').then((interception) => {
  //Do something
})
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However, I've added it to my code & still getting the same error. I'm not sure why though, because the call is being made in the network tab above

Comment: A user doesn't need to specify the GET portion, the issue is his base url will never ever match what he is trying to intercept.